# how to delete a branch from a repo in sourcetree with only 1 branch?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have SourceTree installed on my local environment.  I'm working within a shared collection of git repos for at an enterprise.  Looks like the admin created a new repo RepoY and we previously only had 1 repo (RepoX).  I accidentally created BranchZ in RepoY and I need to delete it.

I selected BranchZ through SourceTree under RepoY, right-clicked and I was able to "Remove" it but now it displays with a red minus sign to the left. I tried to "Delete" the branch but SourceTree returns the following error: "error: Cannot delete the branch 'BranchZ' which you are currently on."

I'm not able to switch branches within the repo because BranchZ is the only branch in the repo.  If I double-click a different repo in SourceTree then I can only delete RepoY but not BranchZ within RepoY.  Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do through SourceTree or is this a limitation of SourceTree?

Comment: It is not a limitation of SourceTree. The error message comes from `Git`.

Comment: Is it a local branch or remote branch?

Answer (score 6):

You are not allow to delete the branch which you are on, firstly you have checkout to another branch since it is the only branch you can just simply checkout master branch(every repo has master branch if it wasn't deleted). Then you are able to delete but be sure you are in correct repo.

```
git checkout master
git push origin :<branchName> (it deletes local and remote branch in case of you already pushed commits)
```

Comment: Please add some comments and contect..that will help users

Answer (score 4):

When you create a git repository using `git init`, master branch will be created by default. I think in your case master branch may be deleted by some mistake, or you accidently renamed it. So, in this case, what you can do from SourceTree is,

1. Create a branch called `master`
2. Checkout `master` branch
3. Delete `BranchZ` branch

Or from command line,

```
cd <repo_dir>
git branch master
git checkout master
git branch -d BranchZ
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in Sourcetree's UI nowadays.

Go to the (remote) branch view, select the node you want to delete, right click, select **Branch...**
In the Branch Window switch to the **Delete Branches** tab..

[image]

Delete or force delete branches as needed, then checkout again.

Comment: What are the exact steps to open remote branch view?  I cannot find that menu or button choice any where in sourectree.

Comment: @just_a_programmer You should be able to find them in the Side pane of the Sourcetree UI. I will check again in case.

Comment: I do not see the menu option "branch" following the directions above.  I think its either moved or my sourcetree version.  thanks for posting this though :)

Comment: @just_a_programmer Are you logged in using SSH or HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

I tried on source tree but it did not succeed. The best approach to make it is logging in to your bitbucket and deleting the branch from there. You can delete the target branch with your terminal locally.

Bitbucket:
**Branches -> Your Target Branch -> "Delete" action from (...) menu.**

Delete local branch:

```
git checkout master
git branch -d target-branch
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sourcetree app,

1. Navigate to Repository -> Branch -> Delete Branches tab
2. Select the branches you want to delete
3. Delete Branches

Answer (score 0):

When using SourceTree, you can delete branches **one at a time** by right-clicking on the branch and selecting "Delete." However, if you want to **delete multiple branches simultaneously**, you can follow these steps using the TortoiseGit UI:

Right-click on the project folder.
Choose TortoiseGit from the context menu.
Select 'Browse References' from the TortoiseGit submenu.
From the 'Browse References' window, you should be able to select and delete multiple branches at the same time.
By following these steps, you can efficiently manage and delete multiple branches using the TortoiseGit UI.